# How to handle numbers embedded in text during NLP pre-processing?

Tags: python, nlp, lda

I am trying to run the LDA algorithm on a data set of news articles.
I understand that numbers must be removed during the pre-processing step, and I have written a simple regex code to replace numbers with blanks.

```
df['number_removed'] = df['text'].str.replace('\d+', '',regex=True)
```

However, I would like to retain some numbers since removing them can potentially change the context/topic.
For example,

[Desired] 'The fourth industrial revolution also referred to as Industry 40 is starting to change the way goods are produced'

[Wrong] 'The fourth industrial revolution also referred to as Industry is starting to change the way goods are produced'

Note: The punctuations have been removed in the example as part of pre-processing

So, I was wondering:

1. Can essential numbers be retained before running LDA?
2. How to selectively remove numbers or handle the above situation?

Comment: If what you want to keep is specific phrases like "Industry 4.0", then it's worth thinking of this as part of tokenization.  Just like the tokenization step should preserve "New York" as a single token rather than splitting it into "New" and "York", you want it to keep "Industry 4.0".  Then later in your pipeline you can filter out tokens which are purely numbers, and this one won't be affected.  Here's an example of how that's done in SpaCy: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#retokenization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is sometimes done in similar situations is to replace numbers with a dummy token, such as `<NUMBER>`, so that the fact that there was a number in the original text is preserved, but without disturbing the syntactic context. The actual value is usually not that important for generalisations.

If you want to retain concrete numbers (like "industry 40") then I guess you need to adjust your regex to keep those patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Modifying the Regex seems like a better solution to this, since I want to create a generalised solution